# perl FTP to z/OS, preventing userid from being prepended to destination file name

Tags: perl, ftp, zos

I'm trying to write a perl script (below) to automate an upload of source files from Windows to z/OS (aka MVS or OS/390).  The put() method appears to be prefixing the remote dataset (file) name on z/OS with the userid that I have logged on with ("JCARTER").  The remote dataset name that I want to upload to is "FSI.V121P01.INSTALL", and it is a Partitioned Data Set (PDS).  This prefixing of the destination dataset name with "JCARTER" causes the dataset to be not found and the put() fails.  I've tried different ways of quoting the destination file name but my userid is still prepended to the file name.  I've also tried using cwd() to set the cwd, using quote('SITE', 'QUOTESOVERRIDE') and quote('SITE', 'DATASETMODE'), but still no success.

Here's the script:

```
use strict;
use Net::FTP;

my $HostIP="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
my $ftp;

$ftp = Net::FTP -> new ($HostIP) or die "Cannot connect to zOS: $@";
$ftp->login("userid","pw") or die "Cannot login.", $ftp->message;
$ftp->ascii();

#$ftp->cwd();
#$ftp->quot('SITE', 'QUO');
#$ftp->quot('SITE', 'DATAS');
print $ftp->message;
$ftp->pwd();
print $ftp->message;
$ftp->put('J:\REL122\RPS100\A2WBLIB\C\a2wversn.c', 'FSI.V121P01.INSTALL(A2WVERSN)');
print $ftp->message;
$ftp->quit;
```

Running the program above results in the messages below:

Representation type is Ascii NonPrint
"'JCARTER.'" is working directory.
JCARTER.FSI.V121P01.INSTALL(A2WVERSN) requests a nonexistent partitioned data se
t.  Use MKD command to create it.

When I try adding a cwd(""), to remove the current working directory, I get:

Representation type is Ascii NonPrint
"'JCARTER.'" is working directory.
"/" is the HFS working directory.
Storing data set /FSI.V121P01.INSTALL(A2WVERSN)
Open of /FSI.V121P01.INSTALL(A2WVERSN) failed.

It seems that I'm pretty close.  Any suggestions ?  Thanks - John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like when you connect via the FTP, the dataset it drops you in is named "JCARTER," per your username.

Have you tried cdup () to take you up out of that JCARTER named dataset? Then you may be able to cwd() into the FSI.V121P01.INSTALL PDS.

If that doesn't work, you may want to just establish the connection, run dir() and take a look at what Net::FTP returns for you.  That might make things more logically navigable.

Comment: Nick - yes, adding cdup() worked !  The cdup() appears to have removed the "JCARTER." working directory that I was dropped into when my FTP session was started.  The FTP messages that I saw after using cdup() led me to believe that I might also be able to use cwd("''"), so I tried that and that worked too.  You saved me a lot of time.    Thanks.

Comment: z/OS PDSs aren't related to directories.  There is some syntactic sugar in z/OS that makes non-HFS datasets (like PDSs) look like they are composed of directories, but those are just dataset name qualifiers.  If you could surround your dataset name with apostrophes, that would probably fix your problem too.  I believe the non-HFS file system predates directories (late 1960s).  Nothing wrong with this solution, just pointing something out.  Carry on.

Comment: @cschneid - yes, I just tried enclosing the destination file name in single quotes inside of double quotes and that worked as well. $ftp->put('J:\REL122\RPS100\A2WBLIB\C\a2wversn.c', "'FSI.V121P01.INSTALL(A2WVERSN)'");
I should have tried that earlier.  Thanks for the additional info.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the clarification.  Hopefully my edit uses the appropriate terminology.  I haven't actually worked with z/OS PDSs before - I just know that sometimes Net::FTP does not connect you to the most intuitive location and a cdup() or similar navigation call can ease a lot of headaches.